# Principle of I/E: In how many ways can eight cakes be distributed among four kids if every kid receives at least one cake?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

Eight cakes are distributed randomly among four kids. Use I/E to determine in how many of the possible distributions every kid receives at least $1$ cake.

Hint: Define $A_i$ to be the set of distributions where the $i$th kid does not receive any cake. Compute $|\cap_{i \in I}  A_i|$ if $|I| = k \leq 4$.

Comment: The problem is asking you to subtract those distributions in which one or more children do not receive a cake from the total number of distributions.  For instance, $A_1$ is the set of distributions in which the first child does not receive a cake, meaning that the eight cakes are distributed to the remaining three children.  You should start the problem by determining in how many ways eight cakes could be distributed to four children without restriction.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig do you know a formula to solve it? I don't get it

Comment: The Inclusion-Exclusion Principle for four sets is \begin{align*}|A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup A_4| & = |A_1| + |A_2| + |A_3| + |A_4| \\ & \quad  - |A_1 \cap A_2| - |A_1 \cap A_3| - |A_1 \cap A_4| - |A_2 \cap A_3| - |A_2 \cap A_4| - |A_3 \cap A_4|\\ & \quad + |A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3| + |A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_4| + |A_1 \cap A_3 \cap A_4| + |A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4|\\ & \quad - |A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4|\end{align*}  You need to compute $|A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup A_4|$ and subtract it from the total number of ways of distributing eight cakes to four children without restriction.

Comment: without restriction I need to do a binomial coefficient right? @N.F.Taussig

Comment: If there are no restrictions, there are four possible recipients for each of the eight cakes, so how many distributions are possible?

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig forget it, I was wrong. How do I obtain the cardinality of A1?

Comment: Let's start with the number of unrestricted distributions.  Since there are four possible recipients for each of the eight cakes, there are $4^8$ ways to distribute the cakes without restriction.  $|A_1|$ represents the number of ways to distribute the cakes if the first child receives none, which means the eight cakes must be distributed to the remaining three children.  How many ways are there to do that?